# Tensor product representation of $SO(3)$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $D^{(1)}$ be the representation of $SO(3)$ such that for $g \in SO(3)$: $D^{(1)}(g)=g$. I need to find an invariant subspace of dimension $1$ (of $\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)$, where $V$ is the representation space of $D^{(1)}$) of $D^{(1)} \otimes D^{(1)}$ but I have no clue how this can be done easily. I tried to write a general element $g \in SO(3)$ in terms of Euler angles and then try to construct the matrix $D^{(1)} \otimes D^{(1)}$, but I got stuck. Any ideas how to attack this problem in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer. Namely, $(D^{(1)} \otimes D^{(1)})(g)$ for $g \in SO(3)$ has an invariant subspace of dimension $1$. This could be found as follows for $w \in W$ with $W$ the $V$-invariant subspace:

$$D^{(1)}(g)wD^{(1)}(g) = w$$

The only possibility is that $w = \mathrm{id}$ and therefore given a basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ for $V$ the invariant subspace $W$ is given by: $\mathrm{span}(e_1 \otimes e_1 + e_2 \otimes e_2 + e_3 \otimes e_3)$. Therefore the subrepresentation of $D^{(1)}$ w.r.t $W$ is the trivial representation $D^{(0)}$.

Comment: $Sym^2(V)$ can be viewed as the space of homogeneous quadratic polynomials (identify the indeterminates with elements of an orthogonal basis of $V$), and $SO(3)$ preserves the lengths of vectors. That is, the quadratic form $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$. The answer follows! In some other cases you may get the dual, but here $V$ is self-dual.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information, quite useful to know